# Store Kit crashes on 2nd request

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit, storekit

i am building my first Store Kit app and have a crash issue:

The app is a Sprite Kit Game

in `MainMenuScene.swift` i allocate the `RemoveAdButton`
when tapped i call the `initPurchaseRemoveAds()` function

**MainMenuScene.swift**e = SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue()

```
    func initPurchaseRemoveAds() {
        let actionRotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_2_PI), duration: 0.1)
        let spin = SKAction.repeatActionForever(actionRotate)
        self.loadingwheel.runAction(spin)
        self.loadingwheel.hidden = false
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(KeyValueKeyClassification.NotificationBuyRemoveAd.rawValue, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    }
```

**GameViewController.swift**

```
var request : SKProductsRequest?
var queue : SKPaymentQueue. = SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue()

// called through the notification (works!)
func initPurchase(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("user clicked remove ads")
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        println("user can make payments")
        self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: PurchaseClassification.RemoveAdID.rawValue as String))
        self.request?.delegate = self
        self.request?.start()
    } else {
        println("user cannot make payments")
    }
}

func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func purchase(product : SKProduct) {
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    var adprodfound : Bool = false
    var count = response.products.count
    if count > 0 {
        for p in response.products {
            if p is SKProduct {
                var prod = p as SKProduct
                if prod.productIdentifier == PurchaseClassification.RemoveAdID.rawValue as String {
                    println("remove ad product available")
                    adprodfound = true
                    purchase(prod)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if !adprodfound {
        println("remove ad product not available")
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("received restored transactions")

    for t in queue.transactions {
        if t is SKPaymentTransaction {
            var trans = t as SKPaymentTransaction
            if trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionState.Restored {
                println("transactionstate = restored")
                removeAds()
                break
             }
        }
    }

}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for t in queue.transactions {
        if t is SKPaymentTransaction {
            var trans = t as SKPaymentTransaction
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchasing:
               break
            case .Purchased:
                removeAds()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
                 break
           case .Restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
           case .Failed:
                if trans.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled {
                        println("Transaction state -> Cancelled")
                }
                stopWheel()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                stopWheel()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
            }
        }
    }
}

func stopWheel() {
    println("stop wheel")
```

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(KeyValueKeyClassification.NotificationStopWheel.rawValue, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    }

```
func removeAds() {
    stopWheel()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: KeyValueKeyClassification.KeyAdsRemoved.rawValue)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(KeyValueKeyClassification.NotificationRemoveAds.rawValue, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

**Problem**
* purchase works fine when done once
* app crashes if i abort the purchase (wheel stops spinning, everything fine) and then tap the `RemoveAds` button again

error reproduction:

- click remove ad purchase
- cancel purchase
- click remove ad purchase again

output:

```
user clicked remove ads
user can make payments
remove ad product available
stop wheel
user clicked remove ads
user can make payments
(lldb) bt
thread #1: tid = 0x3186, 0x0000000102abd00b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x0000000102abd00b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
    frame #1: 0x000000010084eeee StoreKit`__34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 52
    frame #2: 0x0000000107070ba6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #3: 0x000000010708e7f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #4: 0x00000001070778fb libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 949
    frame #5: 0x00000001012e9fe9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #6: 0x00000001012aceeb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    frame #7: 0x00000001012ac486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #8: 0x00000001031819f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #9: 0x000000010176e420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
  * frame #10: 0x000000010061a3ae shapesly`top_level_code + 78 at AppDelegate.swift:14
    frame #11: 0x000000010061a3ea shapesly`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #12: 0x00000001070c3145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

error:

```
[app.GameViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc2fc845880
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your problem is that SKProductsRequest is not being retained.

The best solution is to move your StoreKit logic to a helper class:

```
class StoreKitHelper: NSObject,SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKRequestDelegate {
var request : SKProductsRequest?
var queue : SKPaymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue()


class var defaultHelper : StoreKitHelper {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : StoreKitHelper = StoreKitHelper()
    }

    return Static.instance
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}


func initPurchase() {
    println("user clicked remove ads")
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        println("user can make payments")
        self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: PurchaseClassification.RemoveAdID.rawValue as String))
        self.request?.delegate = self
        self.request?.start()
    } else {
        println("user cannot make payments")
    }
}

...
```

you can then init a purchase without notifications like so:

```
StoreKitHelper.defaultHelper.initPurchase()
```

this way you can be sure that all properties are retained and the above error will not reoccur.

Comment: i did that (see updated code & output). sadly the result is the same. on the second purchase the app crashes :/

Comment: Are you certain BTW, that the GameViewController is not being deallocated? With this type of an error, it typically is that something has been deallocated. What do you mean by "abort the purchase"?

Comment: it's the only viewcontroller (Sprite Kit game), so no i dont think it's deallocated... aborting the purchase means to click `cancel` on the Login Popup for the purchase in this case

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Can you add a deinit with a println just to make sure?

Comment: found a new error message see log in question. i'll add that right now `message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc2fc845880` how can i trace this instance?

Comment: o_O deinit actually gets called! how can i avoid this?

Comment: Okay, so backtracking a bit. You won't need that property for the request, as it is the delegate (GameViewController) that is being deallocated. Heh, it was one or the other, I just started with the wrong one ;). Set a breakpoint for deinit and see who is calling it. I think I have a solution for you, I'm now just curious on who is calling it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65865/discussion-between-sebastian-fluckiger-and-mobile-ben).

Comment: Since it is being deinit, you should clear out the delegate for the request. self.request?.delegate = nil and then self.request = nil. Another way you can do this is have a singleton for a ProductManager. Note you'll still need to get the VC the results, which would still mean needing to properly handle that as well.